# In phoenix for hbase , upsert OOM when insert 90000 row data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, upsert, apache-phoenix

Run cmd :

> ./jsvc64/jsvc64 -pidfile ./log/jsvc.pid -outfile ./log/out.txt -errfile ./log/error.txt -Xmx512m  -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true  -cp :./tools/lib/*:./tools/*  com.g2us.hbase.cmdlog.monitor.CmdLogHbase ./

SQL :

> UPSERT INTO CMDLOG_20130818(game,roleid,otime,logtype,passport,subgame,cmdid,exception,moreinfo,pname_0,pname_1,pname_2)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

upsert 90000 row data,the exception occored.

How to solve it.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:143)
    at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.copyMethod(ReflectAccess.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.copyMethod(ReflectionFactory.java:282)
    at java.lang.Class.copyMethods(Class.java:2748)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Invocation.<init>(Invocation.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
    at $Proxy8.getClosestRowBefore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1019)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.access$000(MetaScanner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner$1.connect(MetaScanner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.execute(HConnectionManager.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:947)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:263)
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.query.HTableFactory$HTableFactoryImpl.getTable(HTableFactory.java:60)
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.getTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:133)
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.execute.MutationState.commit(MutationState.java:227)
    at com.salesforce.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixConnection.commit(PhoenixConnection.java:244)
    at com.g2us.hbase.phoenix.HBaseHelper.executeUpdate(HBaseHelper.java:62)
    at com.g2us.hbase.cmdlog.io.BaseLogPoster.upsertRow(BaseLogPoster.java:153)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it.

the problem that 's  preStat define as class field var ,so that call executeQuery() many time no close it ,then OutOfMemoryError.

error code:

```
public class F{
PreparedStatement preStat = null;  

public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql, Object... args) throws Exception {
    ResultSet rsResultSet = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stat = null;
    try {

        conn = HBaseUtility.getConnection();
        preStat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (args != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                preStat.setObject(i + 1, args[i]);
            }
        }
        rsResultSet = preStat.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dispos(conn, stat);
        Log.error(Log.DB, "queryerror|", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("hbase query error");
    } finally {
        HBaseUtility.release(conn);
    }
    return rsResultSet;
}

}
```

fixed code:

```
public class F{
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql, Object... args) throws Exception {
    ResultSet rsResultSet = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stat = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement preStat = null;  //this var as a class var ,and no close every query .
        conn = HBaseUtility.getConnection();
        preStat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (args != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                preStat.setObject(i + 1, args[i]);
            }
        }
        rsResultSet = preStat.executeQuery();
        preStat.close();  //must be close.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dispos(conn, stat);
        Log.error(Log.DB, "queryerror|", e);
        throw new RuntimeException("hbase query error");
    } finally {
        HBaseUtility.release(conn);
    }
    return rsResultSet;
}

}
```